# pkg-config unable to find existing libproj installation on windows

Tags: sqlite, rust, proj

I already have installed proj using OSGeo installation and sqlite3 with CMake but I got the following error:

```
pkg-config unable to find existing libproj installation: 
  pkg-config exited with status code 1
  > PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags proj proj >= 9.2.0

  The system library `proj` required by crate `proj-sys` was not found.
  The file `proj.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.
  The PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is not set.

  HINT: if you have installed the library, try setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing proj.pc.

  building libproj from source
  disabling tiff support
  CMake Deprecation Warning at cmake/Ccache.cmake:10 (cmake_minimum_required):
    Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
    CMake.

    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:126 (include)


  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:181 (message):
    sqlite3 dependency not found!
```

How Can I fix that?